# Django i18n URL media file no found

Tags: django-i18n

I have activated i18n in my Django project and used i18n_patterns in my `urls.py`. All translations work fine and change whenever the language code in the URL changes. The problem comes to the picture in the media folder.

I have a few pictures in the media folder as the slider background and they get changed every few seconds. With this i18n_patterns, it reads media files from `/en/media/` instead of `/media/`. In this case, I created the `/en/media/` folder just for English and created the same folder `/zh/media/` folder for Chinese. But the problem is, it always returns 404 even the images are there. All images in the `/zh/media/` folder do not show. And only 2 out of 4 images in the `/en/media/` folder shows. This is very confusing to me. Hope you guys have any idea of what is happening here.

Below is the portion of code in related files:

**settings.py**

```py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
]

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('zh', _('Chinese')),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [

]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**template.html**

```html
<img src="media/{% image_file_name %}" />
```

On the console, it shows as follows even though the file is present.

```
[TIMESTAMP] "GET /zh/media/XXX.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2798
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to use `<img src="media/{% image_file_name %}" />`.

Instead do this `<img src="{{ image_field.url }}" />`. The url will get rendered properly using this. You may read more on this topic in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/).